# Reflow-able epub SDK for iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, epub

I know Adobe® Reader Mobile software development kit is able to render Reflow-able epub  for iOS / Android. But their high cost is impossible for normal user to use.

Are there any free/value alternative for a epub SDK that support Reflow-able content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used it yet, but I have found this one:

http://epub.anfengde.com/

Looks really interesting.

Comment: Looks like the last updates are 2 years ago, does anyone know if this is still an active project?